# NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains EXC_BAD_ACCESS code = 2

Tags: ios, xcode, persistent-data

This is my first stab at persistent data. It seems the data was saved (as it is supposed to automatically load the data into the view when it opens). now when I add the view I get the crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7...)

here is the function

```
- (NSString *) dataFilePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.archive"];
}
```

Here is the line with the crash

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

any ideas on what the problem is?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. If this is the problem it is the context that it is in. Have you posted the entire error message?

Comment: yes, just the bad access code 2, followed by the memory address

Comment: I made a new project that only contains the save/load code, and it works fine. This means the code itself is fine, the problem lies in how it is implemented with the rest of my app. This thread is effectively dead. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I fixed it. It was a simple scope problem. I called this code in the class that manages the data, instead of the class that calls the view to be created. So problem solved.

Comment: I know this is semi resolved, just noted there are hints that Apple has some background tasks that might interfere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246270/exc-bad-access-on-nssearchpathfordirectoriesindomains It appears that system call needs to be in the foreground, or "after init", as you have seen. I want to dig into this.